# Spring Boot Rest API-Invalid Request Param Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Computer] did not match expected type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How do implement search from `OneToMany` entities? I have `Book and`Category` domain models.

```
public class Category {
   private long id;
   private String name;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Book> books;
}

public class Book {
   private long id;
   private String title;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
   private Category category;
}
```

This is my method in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public String findAll(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) String category) {
   if (category != null && !category.isEmpty()) {
      model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findByCategory(category));
   } else {
      model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findAll());
   }

   return "book/findAll";
}
```

My service:

```
@Override
public Iterable<Book> findByCategory(String category) {
   return bookRepository.findByCategory(category);
}
```

And my repository:

```
Iterable<Book> findByCategory(String category);
```

With request `/books/?category=Computer`, I'm the following error on browser:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Parameter value [Computer] did not match expected type [io.github.julianjupiter.springbootjpamanytoone.domain.Category (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Computer] did not match expected type [io.github.julianjupiter.springbootjpamanytoone.domain.Category (n/a)]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think the previous title is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove / after

> books

and try in your repository

```
 Iterable <Book> findByCategoryName(String categoryName);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but it should be `findByCategoryName`.

Comment: oh, obviously it should be Name not title. I just overlooked it. I have updated my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are used by following way:

```
/books?category=Computer
```

Remove **/**

Comment: I think it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your Request Mapping method having a `@RequestParam` not `@PathVariable`.

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public String findAll(Model model,@RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) String category) {
...
...
...
// Your Code
}
```

So, Correct way to put a request having a QueryParam / RequestParam would be

```
/books?category=Computer // this request enables to get the service /books with request param (name = category) with value = Computer.
```

not like this

```
/books/?category=Computer  // this request is a invalid request.
```

If your mapping is like that

```
    @GetMapping("/books/category/{categoryName}")
    public String findAll(Model model,@PathVariable("categoryName") String category) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    // Your Code
    }
```

then this request is valid for this Rest-API

```
/books/category/Computer  // this request is a valid now.
```

Comment: If we follow the naming convention of REST API, it should be `/books`, `/books/{id}`, `/books/{id}/categories`, `/books/{bookId}/categories/{categoryId}`

Comment: But I can't apply it under `BookController` since the purpose is to search all books whose category is the same as the value of `category` `RequestParam`. It should be under `CategoryController`.